# Is it possible to have an animation occur over a set number of scrolled pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

What I want to do is:

After a user has scrolled 600 pixels down the page (or 20% down the page), over the next 800 pixels (or the next 10% distance of the page) an animation occurs. Text will move from right to left, so from 0 to -200%. It should begin animating at 600 pixels and end animating at 1400 pixels. Is this possible?

At the moment I want to do this:

```
$('.div1').css({
    'position' : 'fixed',
    'top' : '-32%',
    'display' : 'block',
    'width' : '100%'
}).addClass('locked');
```

to the top div once 600px has been reached, to force it to not move while the next div will animate. How do I prevent the rest of the page from scrolling up while my text is animating and potentially covering the content?

Comment: To prvent things from "moving up" you'd have to wrap these `.div1` divs in another div that doesn't animate and retains the original positioning (as soon as you set `position:fixed` it is removed from the standard layout flow, and everything "shifts up" to compensate).

Answer (score 0):

Skrollr does this.

Check it out.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr